# GROUP BY not working - not aggregating

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that continues to  give me multiple lines. I am pulling information from two tables and it appears that the aggregate function is not working. 
Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    StageAttributeData.A1, 
    StageAttributeData.A3, 
    SUM(isnull(cast(StageSourceData.Am as float),0))  AS '(Stage)'
FROM StageSourceData 
INNER JOIN StageAttributeData ON  StageSourceData.Ri = StageAttributeData.RI
INNER JOIN vStageSourceAndTargetData ON vStageSourceAndTargetData.RI = StageSourceData.Ri
WHERE StageSourceData.si = 'WarrantyDetail'
Group By StageAttributeData.A1,StageAttributeData.A3
```

These are the results I continue to receive:

[image]

The Beginning Balance column is not aggregating with the remaining columns and in some instances the amount is being replicated in all three columns.

Comment: There are columns in your 'results' that you aren't selecting...

Comment: The results' columns don't match the query at all; an aggregation query such as the one you've presented SHOULD "give multiple lines" if there is more than one `(A1, A3)` pair.

Answer (score 0):

i think you  must  add  to  "group by"  StageSourceData.Am

Comment: what your reasoning? that would just add all the columns in the select to the group by statement, would that work?